# How to return a value from an if let statement inside a function?

Tags: swift, if-statement, switch-statement, return-value, option-type

I am learning Swift by myself from official Apple Curriculum Books, which unfortunately do not come with solutions. I find myself stuck with this problem.

> Write a function that will take the name of an item for purchase and
> will return the cost of that item. In the body of the function, check
> to see if the item is in stock by accessing it in the dictionary
> stock. If it is, return the price of the item by accessing it in the
> dictionary prices. If the item is out of stock, return nil. Call the
> function and pass in a String that exists in the dictionaries below.
> Print the return value.

These are the provided dictionaries.

```
var prices = ["Chips": 2.99, "Donuts": 1.89, "Juice": 3.99, "Apple": 0.50, "Banana": 0.25, "Broccoli": 0.99]
var stock = ["Chips": 4, "Donuts": 0, "Juice": 12, "Apple": 6, "Banana": 6, "Broccoli": 3]
```

The first part of the problem is quite simple. This is the code I wrote:

```
func itemInStock(item: String) -> Int? {
    
    if let availableItems = stock[item] {
        switch availableItems {
        case 1...Int.max:
            print("\(item) are available: \(availableItems) items.")
            if let price = prices[item] {
                print("\(item) cost \(price) USD per item.")
                return Int(price)
            }
            
        default:
            print("Sorry, \(item) are out of stock")
            return nil
        }
    
    }
    return Int(price)
}
```

Without `-> Int?` and `return` lines it works fine.
When I added `return Int(price)` and `return nil`, Xcode gave me an error message: "Missing return in function...".

So I added another `return Int(price)` line in the end. But Xcode says that it cannot find it in scope.

How can I get that `price` value from inside `if-let` statement?

Even if I declare a variable inside the function then set its new value with `price` inside the `switch`, it will still have its initial value outside the `switch`.

It seems that there is a very simple way to handle these situations, but I couldn't find them anywhere. And I tried searching with different keywords.

**UPD** thanks, to Joakim Danielson I managed to get a much more concise code:

```
func itemInStock_V2(item: String) -> Double? {
    if let availableItems = stock[item], availableItems > 0 {
            print("\(item) are available: \(availableItems) items.\n\(item) cost \(String(describing: prices[item])) USD per item.")
            return prices[item]
        } else {
            print("Sorry, \(item) are out of stock")
            return nil
    }
}
```

I didn't know that it was possible to add another condition right after `if let` declaration.

And it turned out that my problem was that I had to write `return` command after *every* outcome of the code even if it would never happen.

Comment: Your function should return a double since that is the type of price,`-> Double?`. And you don’t need the switch at all, instead extend the `if let` with another condition `, availableItems > 0`. Then you can return the price from inside the if and nil outside of it. And if you use a local variable in the function instead then initialize it to nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, xcode doesn't know what to return if if-let statements don't work, this should help:

```
func itemInStock(item: String) -> Int? {
    if let availableItems = stock[item] {
    
        switch availableItems {
        case 1...Int.max:
            print("\(item) are available: \(availableItems) items.")
            if let price = prices[item] {
                print("\(item) cost \(price) USD per item.")
                return Int(price)
            } else {
                // in case (if let price = prices[item]) didn't work
                return nil
            }
            
        default:
            print("Sorry, \(item) are out of stock")
            return nil
        }
        
    } else {
        // in case (if let availableItems = stock[item]) didn't work
        return nil
    }
}
```

you can also use guard-let if you immediately want to get rid of return nil statements

Answer (score 0):

You only return from the if statement and never otherwise. I think it must be something like:

```
func itemInStock(item: String) -> Int? {

    if let availableItems = stock[item] {
        switch availableItems {
        case 1...Int.max:
            print("\(item) are available: \(availableItems) items.")
            if let price = prices[item] {
                print("\(item) cost \(price) USD per item.")
               return Int(price)
           }
        default:
            print("Sorry, \(item) are out of stock")
            return nil
        }

    } else {
       return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
func itemCost(item: String) -> Double? {
    if let available = stock[item] {
        if available == 0 {
            // none available
            return nil
        } else {
            // return the price
            return prices[item]
        }
    } else {
        // unknown item
        return nil
    }
}
```